# C# ASP.NET document.getElementById not getting elments

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have done searches for this but could not find an answer that worked.

I am trying to access the asp:TextBox ID="wordList" node details and its keep return count = 0. I have tried two alternate methods as can be seen below in the javascript and do not understand why its not working. Can anyone see the reason?

Many Thanks
Jaie

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Week3.WebForm1" Theme="Theme1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Grid Details</title>

</head>
<body>
    <script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
        function ValidateWordList() {
            var x = document.getElementById("wordList").innerHTML;
            x += "Length" + x.length;
            alert(x);
            var z = document.getElementById('<%= wordList.ClientID %>').innerHTML;
            alert(z);    
            return false;
        }
    </script>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="form1Box">

        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblWord" runat="server" Text="Word(s) of Puzzle:"><asp:TextBox ID="wordList" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/></asp:Label>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorWordList" ControlToValidate="wordList" 
             CssClass="Validation" runat="server" Text="(Required)" />
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidatorWordList" ControlToValidate="wordList" runat="server" CssClass="Validation"
              ValidationExpression="(^[a-zA-Z ,]*$)"  ErrorMessage="(The word(s) can only be letters, space or comma's!)"/> 

        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Generate Puzzle" runat="server"  OnClientClick="return ValidateWordList()"/>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Double quotes come to mind

Comment: Tried that too and it didn't work

Comment: ClientIDMode="Static" <- Never used that one before, is it important somewhere else in your code?

Comment: If you view the source in the browser, what do you see in place of `<%= wordList.ClientID %>`? Does it match the ID on the textbox?

Comment: For the ClientIDMode: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx#Y0 it should be working with just document.getElementById("wordList").innerHTML;

Comment: @JLRishe Yes it all matches <span id="lblWord">Word(s) of Puzzle:<input name="wordList" type="text" id="wordList" /></span>

Comment: Wait... I thought you were meaning that getting by "wordlist" worked and `wordlist.ClientID` didnt - which works - which doesnt??

Comment: That textbox Id will change to a server side Id of ct1000_wordlist hence not recognising the original Id

Comment: Neither JavaScript method works

Comment: If your `ValidateWordList()` function actually looks like it does in your sample, the function is probably erroring out when you try to access the `innerHTML` property on an `undefined` value.

Comment: Problem solved as Below, Still learning so I make mistakes ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to retrieve whatever value user has entered in the textbox? If so, you are probably looking for:

```
var x = document.getElementById("wordList").value;
```

Text fields do not define any inner markup, and their property `innerHtml` in most cases is just an empty string.

Comment: Bah that's it, many thanks Visual Studio wasn't generating that option.